# Accessing MySQL docker container from Flask APP

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have been trying all day, unsuccessfully, to connect to a MySQL running container from my SQLALCHEMY flask app. Don't know what I'm doing wrong, perhaps I'm missing something that you might call my attention to resolve my issue.

Just for context.

I have the following files:

docker-compose.yml file with MySQL and Adminer:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: master
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - mysqlcomposenetwork
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 100:100
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - mysqlcomposenetwork

networks: 
  mysqlcomposenetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

db.yml file to store connection string information isolated from the app.

```
mysql_host: 'localhost:100'
mysql_user: 'user'
# Enter your password in field below
mysql_password: 'password'
mysql_db: 'mysqldb'
```

And finally my app.py, which is a basic Flask app leveraging ORM via flask_sqlalchemy module. Note that before running app.py the mysql and adminer container are both running and db.yml file is in the same directory of app.py; thus, accessible.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql
import datetime
import yaml


app = Flask(__name__)
db = yaml.full_load(open('db.yml'))

#mysql://username:password@host:port/database_name
connection_str='mysql+pymysql://'+db['mysql_user']+':'+db['mysql_password']+'@'+db['mysql_host']+'/'+db['mysql_db']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=connection_str
print(connection_str)


db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Visitor(db.Model):
    accessed_at=db.Column(db.Float,primary_key=True)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer)
    page_id=db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self,accessed_at,user_id,page_id):
        self.accessed_at=accessed_at
        self.user_id=user_id
        self.page_id=page_id




if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        visitor=Visitor(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp(),1000,5)
        db.session.add(visitor)
        db.session.commit()
        print(Visitor.query.all())
```

After running app..py the following error is prompted:
**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061]**

Already tried to change mysql_host: 'localhost:100' to mysql_host: 'db:100' and  mysql_host: 'db'. None of them working...

I appreciate your attention and possible feedback to help me overcome this crippling issue in my program.

I am unable to connect to MySQL container databased from outside. Specifically, from a flask app.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved your question in this github repo :

https://github.com/jcroyoaun/stackoverflow-flask-question

I would appreciate if you could clone my repo and try

```
docker-compose up --build
```

first.

After that, if it works for you please read on the explanation of what was wrong. (I modified a few things after running it on my Mac as I have to specify platform: "linux/amd64" because I use an M1 chip with arm architectore and container for mysql image wouldn't run on my local, so if you have any issues while running it, post them here)

NOTE : for simplicity, I'm only adding the lines of code that I changed from the one you shared.

For a full view of the codebase, please see the repo shared above.

**What I changed from your code**

1. changed on main.py

```
connection_str='mysql://'+db['mysql_user']+':'+db['mysql_password']+'@'+db['mysql_host']+'/'+db['mysql_db']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=connection_str
print(connection_str)
```

EXPLANATION :
-> I didn't need pymysql for your particular situation, so I had it removed from the connection string

2. then on your db.yml file, I changed from

```
mysql_host: 'localhost:100'
```

to

```
mysql_host: 'db:3306'
```

EXPLANATION : -> When you use networking in Docker compose, value of a service name can be resolved as a hostname. Networking wise, your "adminer" Flask app, being in a different container, cannot resolve "localhost" as something outside of itself, therefore, you ma use a hostname as it relies on DNS resolution so that it can connect to another host from the outside world outside of the adminer container.

I also changed the port, as by default, mysql listens to port 3306 so internally mapping port 100 wouldn't make sense unless you modify the configurations of the base docker image ([source](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/e0d43b2a29867c5b7d5c01a8fea30a086861df2b/5.7/Dockerfile.debian))

1. I changed the ports on db service declared on the docker-compose.yml as well, this way we allow the connection to go through by matching the connection string read from db.yml ports we changed earlier. Changes went from

```
    ports:
      - 100:100
```

to

```
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Until this point, the connection works fine, however I found some bugs on your code that I needed to modify as well.

**Additional tweaks I made**

First, I had to re-create your schema and add a table with a few parameters changed. You had the accessed_at defined as

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor` (
  `accessed_at` float(10,7),
```

but then you're passing numbers like
1668759725.166818

Essentially what 10,7 means is that you want :

- 10 total units of precision
- with 7 units past the decimal place, hence
- only 3 units before the decimal place

Therefore I added :

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor` (
  `accessed_at` float(18,6),
```

As I found it more appropriate for the epoch timestamps you were passing as the primary key.

Some other things I changed briefly (you can see on the GitHub repo)

a) I think it's a good practice to copy a schema.sql to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ to pre-load the tables and have them ready for your first-time run of the application+db, otherwise you'll have to insert the schema name and tables manually the first time. I created a Dockerfile for this under ./mysqldockerfile/Dockerfile dir on the project.

b) I also modified the volume you mounted around line 14 on your docker-compose.yml, /var/lib/mysql is usually where the data can be stored/retrieved for the Databases, therefore, mounting a volume from your local (`./data:/var/lib/mysql`) will allow the data inserted to persist after restart (since it's now stored on your local hard drive).

NOTE : there are other bugs / exceptions being thrown, but the connection issue works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the effort put into helping me. Really appreciate that. You're right, I've to use the MySQL container name as the server/host and I need to create an app container containing flask and all python dependencies to make it work. Sadly, your solution didn't work yet on my computer, although it is closer than I was. Thank you.

You can check my repo and clone it https://github.com/Quilograma/IES_Project.
I'm using Kafka too, so I added it to the requirements.txt file. I have two errors mocking me. run.sh file not found and mysql connection persists.